# How to filter in data in sqlite3 where we do not want records of a particular data type to be displayed?

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with two tables in it. There are around 25 columns in one of the table where datatypes of the column are String , int and blob. I do not want the columns which have blob as there type. There are 8 columns which have blob as their type.

[Sample input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POVuf.png)

Comment: Don't use `*`. List just the columns you care about.

Comment: There are multiple columns. I just do not want columns with blob as their type.

Comment: You cannot `SELECT` columns dynamically like that. You either use `SELECT *` or explicitly list the columns you _do_ want. In almost all circumstances, it is far better to list them explicitly.

Comment: There are 25 columns out of which 8 are of blob type.The table is dynamic itself. They will keep on adding the columns.

Comment: We may be in an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) situation, where `Y` is "_selecting the columns that aren't blobs_". It may help if you edit the question to explain the "bigger picture" (`X`) – the sort of data/problem the database is holding, how/when/why the layout of the table is dynamic, and where your "dynamic" query fits into this. _In general_, the need to _regularly_ alter the structure of a table is a sign that things aren't being stored in the right way. [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] One possibility _might_ be to dynamically generate the field-list outside of SQLite (using something like `SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('my_table') WHERE type!='BLOB'`) and then plug that into an SQLiite query; another _might_ be to move the data in the "dynamic" columns into some kind of a _key-value_ table and keep only the "constant" data in the current table. But to advise on that, we'd need to know more about the "bigger problem".

Comment: "Plug into sqlite query". How does that work?

Comment: @SonaliChaturvedi "_How does that work?_" Depends a lot on the "bigger picture" that this query fits into (hence the request to [edit] in more details), but basically you'd run one query to get the list of (non-blob) column names, create a comma-separated string and use that string to build the main `SELECT ... FROM my_table` query string.

Comment: I have entered sample input and output. Thanks